# Can't Connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just installed the `mysql2` gem for `Windows 8` and had an extremely difficult time doing so. After I installed it, I still can't run my Rails Application.

**System Information**

- Operating System: Windows 8
- Ruby Version: 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [i386-mingw32]

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.17'
```

**Database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: db_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

I get this output in my Development Logs

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-12-03 17:33:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-12-03 17:33:49] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [i386-mingw32]
[2014-12-03 17:33:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=53748 port=3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-03 17:34:07 -0600

Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)):
  mysql2 (0.3.17) lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `connect'
  mysql2 (0.3.17) lib/mysql2/client.rb:70:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:1
8:in `new'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:1
8:in `mysql2_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
  C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection
_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_
connection'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connectio
n'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:792:in `current_version'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:800:in `needs_migration?'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:379:in `check_pending!'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:366:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in
 call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__768443287_
_call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `c
all'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `ca
ll'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tag
ged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `
call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispa
tch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispa
tch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispa
tch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispa
tch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (101.0ms)
```

I ran `netstat -a` to test my connections

```
netstat -a

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address          State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6646           rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8732           rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10243          rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49158          rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49159          rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         rh-pc:49156            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         rh-pc:49157            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        rh-pc:64075            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49156        rh-pc:5354             ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49157        rh-pc:5354             ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63342        rh-pc:63342            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:64075        rh-pc:27015            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:139      rh-pc:0                LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49565    a23-33-171-33:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49566    93.184.215.200:http    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49567    a23-33-171-33:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49568    a23-33-171-33:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49569    a23-33-171-33:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49570    a23-33-171-33:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49571    a23-33-171-33:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49580    a23-33-171-33:https    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49583    a184-50-238-90:http    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49584    a184-50-238-90:http    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49585    a184-50-238-90:http    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49586    a184-50-238-90:http    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49587    a184-50-238-90:http    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49588    a184-50-238-90:http    CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49589    a184-50-238-170:http   CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49590    a184-50-238-170:http   CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49591    a184-50-238-170:http   CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49592    a184-50-238-170:http   CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49593    a184-50-238-170:http   CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:49594    a184-50-238-170:http   CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:51590    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:52160    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:52340    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:53015    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:56954    ord31s21-in-f4:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:56992    ord31s21-in-f0:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:56993    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57369    199.16.156.120:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57382    ord08s13-in-f6:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57455    64.233.182.95:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57488    ord08s06-in-f14:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57490    72.21.91.121:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57492    ord08s11-in-f7:http    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57494    a23-67-60-25:http      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57495    stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57502    us:http                TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57507    cf-190-93-246-58:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57508    cf-190-93-246-58:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57509    cf-190-93-246-58:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57510    cf-190-93-246-58:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57511    cf-190-93-246-58:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57512    cf-190-93-246-58:http  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57514    72.5.205.11:http       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57515    ord08s11-in-f7:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57516    ord08s11-in-f7:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57517    72.21.91.121:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57520    a23-67-60-11:http      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57521    a23-67-60-11:http      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57522    103.31.7.32:http       CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57523    103.31.7.32:http       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57524    103.31.7.32:http       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57525    104.16.12.8:http       TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.114:57526    104.16.12.8:http       TIME_WAIT
```

That shows a list of all active connections. I ran this while `rails s` wasn't being run though.

Here is my `lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.17` directory

```
examples (Dir)
ext (Dir)
lib (Dir)
spec (Dir)
support (Dir)
MIT-LICENSE
README.md
```

Here is my `C:/Program Files(x86)/MySQL directory

```
MySQL Connector C 6.1 (Dir)                              # Only file in this folder
```

I spent hours trying to install the gem, and after that have spent another couple hours solving this problem. I can't figure out where the problem is, but I need to fix this.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I dont' see anything listening on port 3306. Did you succeed to connect to your mysql instance using some client? mysqladmin perhaps? Also this line:
```
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```
doesn't look like something that work on win8. And most important: Dude, just use linux for development.

Comment: I cannot figure out why this doesn't work

Comment: Please answer my question: "Did you succeed to connect to your mysql instance using some client? mysqladmin perhaps?"

Comment: I honestly don't even know what mysqladmin is. So I would say no

Comment: Well, then please install mysqladmin, or other mysql client and try to connect to your local mysql instance using this client.

Comment: I Google Searched for MySQLAdmin and couldn't find many results. Is it on a GitHub repository or is it under a different name?

Comment: I am sorry. I actually meant MySQL Workbench. But it can be _any_ client, just to confirm, that you can connect to your mysql instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error of `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'` typically means your MySQL service isn't running.  Are you sure you've pointed your application at the correct host and port for your database service?

Comment: I'm not sure I even have all the proper files. Under `Program Files(x86)/MySQL`, I only have one folder, `MySQL Connector C 6.1`

Comment: You didn't answer the question: Are you sure you've pointed your application at the correct host and port for your database service?

Comment: Yes, MySQL runs on port 3306. I've also tried this without both port and host fields

Comment: You probably need to delete the socket entry in your `Database.yml` file.  I doubt it would try to use a TCP connection if it thought it had a socket available.  More to the point, don't look in `Program Files (x86)`, look in the Services panel (`services.msc`). You should have a MySQL _service_ running, not just the C connector installed.

Comment: I checked `services.msc` and I couldn't find MySQL listed.

Comment: Then you only have the MySQL client installed, you don't actually have a database server running.